# Extract data from async/await function with .then

Tags: javascript, async-await

Iam pretty new to JS and I have a problem with extracting data from an async/await function. The following does work and it prints the correct answer which is a number to the console.

```
fetchData = userData.getPom().then(res => { console.log(res) })
```

But when I try to extract the res outside of the scope of the function it doesnt work, it still prints points as 0.

```
var points = 0
fetchData = userData.getPom().then(res => { points += res })
console.log(points)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

printscreen of both console.logs:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use await instead of then

```
async myfunction () => {     
    var points = 0
    fetchData = await userData.getPom()
    points += fetchData
    console.log(points);
    return points;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let points = 0
userData.getPom().then(res => points += res).then(points => {
  console.log(points)
  // Continue your logic here...
})
```

or with newer [await/async](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp):

```js
async function calcPoints() {
  let points = 0
  let res = await userData.getPom()
  points += res
  console.log(points)
  // Continue your logic here...
  
  return points
}
```

Your problem is related to [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_asynchronous.asp). In your original code it will **instantly console.log(points)** instead of **waiting for the then operations** to be done. So the result will be 0. You can either put another then behind it or use the newer **await and async** technique. (It was invented to get rid of the not good readable then). Check some tutorials about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `points` to the console before the callback function in `then` has been executed.

The order of execution is (probably, but not guaranteed) to be:

- create new fetch promise
- fetch starts running in the 'background'
- print out the value of `points`
- at some point, fetch finishes and we increment `points`

The fetch operation may or may not finish before you get to the line where you print the value of `points`. If you get indeterminate results, this is why.

Essentially for your use case, you need to wait until the request is finished before using/accessing the returned value.

There's two ways to approach fixing this:

Print points in the callback:

```js
fetchData = userData.getPom().then(res => { 
  console.log(res)
})
```

Await the promise before printing

```
async function printPoints() {
  const points = await userData.getPom()
  console.log(points)
}
printPoints()
```

Note for the second, you can only (as of mid 2021, without using special flags or transpilation which may be a bit advanced) use `await` in an `async` function, so we have to wrap this.

Comment: Describes the problem well.. :)